# Copying Excel Chart as a picture into Word Table

Tags: excel, vba, charts, ms-word

Having looked at a number of posts about copying an Excel Chart into a Word document I still cannot get a simple piece of code to work.

I have a workbook that has charts on various worksheets. I am sure I can work out code that will work through the looping issue eventually. Right now I just need code that will copy a chart on one sheet into a Word Table, particular cell.

The word document opens, and I can even see that my code has selected the cell.

I developed the copied code from recording a macro, but of course that is only the copying bit I think as the record function does not record outside of Excel.

My ultimate solution is to have the chart copied as a picture into the Word table. And I need a picture, not a link etc.

My code is:

'''

' Trial copy

```
'xwkBook = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
Sheets(sheetnames(1)).Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
'ActiveChart.ChartArea.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture


    With d
        d.Tables(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Select
        d.Tables(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Paste
       
              
    End With
```

'''

d is defined as

`Dim d As Word.Document`

and is set through the Word file opening process as
`Set d = objW.Documents.Open(strFile)`

and objW as

`Dim objW As Word.Application`

As you can I have tried several options, but I do not get anything pasted into the word table. Yes, Tables(2) does exist in my word file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code logic is close to working. `Range.Paste` will create a linked object. You can get a image in Word table with `PasteSpecial`.

```vb
    'xwkBook = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    
    Dim h As Single, w As Single, img, ratio
    With d.Tables(2).Cell(2, 1).Range
        ' Get the size of cell before pasting
        h = .Rows(1).Height
        w = .Columns(1).Width
        .Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=15, Placement:=wdInLine, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=False
        Set img = .InlineShapes(1)
        ' get the shrink ratio
        ratio = IIf((h / img.Height) < (w / img.Width), h / img.Height, w / img.Width)
        ' resize image to fit cell
        img.Height = img.Height * ratio
    End With
```

---

Please refer to

> [Selection.PasteSpecial method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.pastespecial?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: I tested the code with different variable name. You may need to update it accordingly for your environment. btw, `d.Tables(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Select` directly references `d` so `With d` is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, thank you - it does now work. Much appreciated. The chart is however cropped in the cell. Is there a way of making the chart fit the cell size?